# Does hazelcast in-memory queue scale up when new nodes are added?

Tags: java, hazelcast, blockingqueue

I am trying to implement hazelcast. I was wondering if I use java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue, it sets a max size automatically to it.

Let's say I start a cluster with one node in it, and implement BlockingQueue in it,
next I add one more node to the cluster, so will the queue's maximum size increase as now the cluster has a shared memory of two nodes?

I hope I made my point clear here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made your point clear.

The Hazelcast IQueue implementation is not a partitioned datastructure. So it will be stored completely on a single member (and the backup on another member).

So adding more members to the cluster will not increase the capacity of your queue.

One solution is to create a stripe of queues, so that the whole queue isn't stored on a single member. But it depends if you can deal with a stripe.

Comment: I searched through the Hazelcast documentation and the two Hazelcast books but I could not find anything about queues not being partitioned. Do you know of any documentation that explains the queuing mechanism in a conceptual manner?

Comment: Lets continue the discussion on the mailinglist since you posted a similar question there (and I have replied). If you need to know more, you can ask more questions and I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: that means hazelcast node does not increase scalability it just increases the availablity?

Comment: That is correct.

For Hazelcast 3.5 the IQueue will be enhanced so that the queue is striped over the cluster. So you can add more nodes to the cluster to increase the capacity.